# How do you "compile" something in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, compiling, git

I'm trying to use Gfx Tablet. However, I am struggling to interpret the installation instructions given by the developer.

http://rfc2822.github.io/GfxTablet/#part-1-uinput-driver

His instructions say:

1. Clone the repository: git clone git://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet.git
2. Install gcc, make and linux kernel header includes (kernel-headers on Fedora)
3. cd driver-uinput; make

I have completed the first step and I think I've completed the second step, but then the third step just gets me to the fact that there is no such directory called driver-uinput. I haven't a clue what to do and I bet that this is real simple. Please help and don't kick my question off for nothing! I'm a newbie yes and I know that you Linux users love to bark at someone asking the wrong question in the wrong thread and blah blah blah... Just answer the question. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you cloned the `git` it made a folder called `GfxTablet` in your home folder.

Inside this is `driver-uinput`, change to it like this

```
cd GfxTablet/driver-uinput
```

Then

```
make
```

This makes a file binary called `networktablet` in `GfxTablet/driver-uinput`

Now keep following your instructions.

Comment: The "/" before path is incorrect.

Comment: And why download tar if OP cloned it? It is already there. No need to download or rename anything.

Comment: @Pilot6 Easy for them as they seem  inexperienced and confused, will edit that in

Comment: Your answer is much more confusing. OP is doing according to readme. You suggest doing same thing in a more complicated way.

Comment: @Pilot6 Edited to reflect your comment

Answer (score 0):

Command `cd driver-uinput` is to change directory to "driver-uinput`".

If you cloned git repository to your home folder, then it must be inside "GfxTablet" directory.

You can get there by

```
cd GfxTablet/driver-uinput
```